# When importing from Excel, a percent sign(%) appears in the weird form in my database

Tags: php, excel

I've a code where I upload records as a string from excel file to the MySQL database.
I've used `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function for escaping the special characters.

Eg.

```
//Get the value from excel sheet
$status = $Row[14];

if($row_0)
{
 $status  = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,status); //escape special characters
}
```

But when the record uploaded % character appears a something like this bunch of alphanumeric string in closed in { and },

Eg.

The String

> "Done with 45%"

Appears as

> "Done with
>   45{8c3ac3cd783d55d12e2b27f818a4e6dd41b6fd403bd91d45c7012db83d9dc167}"

What could be the reason for this?
Is it encoding format of the excel file for Database?
Anyone had this kinda issue before?
How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score -1):

`mysqli_real_escape_string` should not do anything to the `%` character:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

> Characters encoded are NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.

Have you verified what the value of the `$status` is *before* you call this function, and what is it immediately after?

Comment: This is not an actual answer, you should add this as a comment, Thanks

Comment: I've checked the uploaded data in mysql database table it replaces the % with {64 digit alphanumeric value}

Is it the encoding Format i use for my excel sheet then?

Comment: Do `var_dump($status)` *before* you do `mysqli_real_escape_string` and let me know what you get